# direct search by a tag's class beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to quickly get only certain `spans` with a certain class using beautiful soup, and I can't seem to search by class, but I can search by ID:

```
In [40]: last_a_tag = soup.find_all("a", id="link3")

In [41]: spans = soup.find_all("span", class="iaLabel")
  File "<ipython-input-41-c15da620dac2>", line 1
    spans = soup.find("span", class="iaLabel")
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This of course doesn't seem very logical, but I don't see an alternative in the doc. I know the soups have an `attrs` dict, I want something fast. Thank you

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Try `class_="iaLabel"` or `{'class': "iaLabel"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the named parameter `class_` not `class`. Note the trailing underscore.

Here's the example from the [bs4 docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class):

```
soup.find_all("a", class_="sister")
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

Comment: there's a term for that, giving things weird names to not collide with the namespace/reserved keywords